# Prevent Firefox autocompletion from popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, autocomplete

I wrote an autocompletion script for an input field on a website. It uses jQuery and works fine. It should look something like this:

[autocomplete-1 http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/1994/screenshot1lm.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/1994/screenshot1lm.png)

Unfortunately, Firefox's own autocompletion gets in my way, overlapping some of the results:
[alt text http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/557/screenshot2ct.png](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/557/screenshot2ct.png)

Is is it possible to prevent the Firefox autocompletion field from popping up? (Not only on my machine but for every user of the website)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the input element in question. E.g.

```
<input autocomplete="off">
```

Also see [this document](https://wiki.mozilla.org/The_autocomplete_attribute_and_web_documents_using_XHTML).

Answer (score 3):

As BalusC already pointed out, you can use the `autocomplete` attribute but you can also add it to the form element so that it affects all elements:

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php" autocomplete="off">
```

Note that this attribute is not part of a standard but most browsers implement it nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Use `autocomplete=off` in the form or input element.

[**Mozilla Developer Central: How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

Answer (score 1):

Use `autocomplete="off"`. It's not valid HTML-code, but widely adopted in browsers.